# Add Expires Header

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

first time coding. I have an issue with Add Expires Header when I tested my website using Gtmertrix, the YSlow reported that I have 60 Add Expires Header.

```
http://www.whirloo.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=4.9.2
http://www.whirloo.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce-layout.css?ver=3.2.6
http://www.whirloo.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce.css?ver=3.2.6
http://www.whirloo.com/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-social-login/assets/css/style.css?ver=4.9.1
http://www.whirloo.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/js_composer.min.css?ver=5.4.5
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600%7CRoboto:400,500,400italic
http://www.whirloo.com/wp-content/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/assets/js/frontend.min.js?ver=6.2.6
http://www.whirloo.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4
http://www.whirloo.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1
http://www.whirloo.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart.min.js?ver=3.2.6
http://www.whirloo.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/js/vendors/woocommerce-add-to-cart.js?ver=5.4.5
http://www.whirloo.com/wp-content/themes/publisher/includes/libs/better-framework/assets/css/bs-icons.css
http://www.whirloo.com/wp-content/plugins/better-social-counter/css/style.min.css
http://www.whirloo.com/wp-content/themes/publisher/includes/libs/better-framework/assets/css/slick.min.css
http://www.whirloo.com/wp-content/plugins/better-adsmanager/css/bam.min.css
```

I have tried using the code from other Add Expires Header post in my .htaccess but it doesn't seem to solve the issue. These are coming from the content in plugins, themes, uploads, and fonts. How can I resolve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On your .htaccess, try to use this:

```
# BEGIN Expire headers
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 7200 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 AddType image/x-icon .ico
 ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 7200 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 7200 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/javascript A2592000
 ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
</IfModule>
# END Expire headers
```

The simpler way to don't worry about that kind of problem is to use Cloudflare. It'll manage all of these configurations for you.